# Rollup -c process is not closed after creating bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, rollup

I'm trying to create rollup build, but when I use `rollup -c` files are created but it doesn't terminate rollup process.
Here is my config

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
    },
  ],
  external: [
    ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
    ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
  ],
  plugins: [
    typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
  ],
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Why the process is not terminated after successful build?

Comment: I had the same issue when I added my package to yarn workspaces. Removing it from there somehow makes it work again.